# How to create a custom field like Email Template

Tags: community

I have created a custom object called email scheduler that have custom fields like template 1, template 2, template 3...etc.

I have created custom date fields like Delivery Date 1, Delivery Date 2, delivery Date 3... etc.

I would like to make the template 1 a picklist value that would fetch the email templates so that when I create a workflow it will send to the contact after clicking save button.

[image]

And make the template 1 field like the Email Template field.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to create a Visualforce Page through an extension collect in a SELECT a list the names of the templates created ?  With this you can generate a dinamic 'Picklist' field in a visualforce, and save the value in another field.

You can storage your templates in a folder and SELECT:

`[SELECT Id, Name FROM EmailTemplate WHERE Folder.DeveloperName = 'MyCustomTemplates']`
*for example*.

Then you can send your email via APEX loading the specified template in your field, feeded via your dinamic visualforce picklist.

--EDITED--

You can use this code: [Visualforce Picklist from Javascript Query](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/119622/visualforce-picklist-from-javascript-query)

Comment: Could we create the code using javascript and visualforce pages instead of apex as I have the professional edition

Comment: Take a look of this link: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.ajax.meta/ajax/sforce_api_ajax_vf_sample.htm

You can try to do with: 
`var templates= sforce.connection.query(
    "select id,name FROM EmailTemplate WHERE Folder.DeveloperName = 'MyCustomTemplates'");`

Comment: Im trying to reproduce it and show you a complete code sample. But I have some problems. I have opened a new question:  http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/119622/visualforce-picklist-from-javascript-query

When we have an answer, I'll edit and complete the upper code

Comment: We have got the answer here: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/119622/visualforce-picklist-from-javascript-query

I hope this can help you friend.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: some formatting

Unfortunately, that's not possible. See [this article](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=08730000000HQ9QAAW).

The only thing that you could do is create a new custom object "Email Template" that stores the unique ID of the Salesforce email template and links it to the display name (so you will need 2 custom fields).

Then you could change the field type of template 1, 2, 3, etc. to a lookup to Email Template. Attention: if you want the Email Template records to stay up to date, you would have to add a new record to this table every time you create a new email template in Salesforce.

Comment: Could you please show an example