# Visualforce Picklist from Javascript Query

Tags: visualforce, javascript, picklist, query, ajax

Can I draw a Picklist in a Visualforce with a Javascript query?

With de ajax connection.js in visualforce, I'm trying to retrieve a list of some values, Ex:

```
var qr = sforce.connection.query(“SELECT Name FROM EmailTemplate WHERE Folder.DeveloperName ='”+ MyCustomTemplates +”‘”);
```

But I have no Idea how to draw the result in a Visualforce Picklist.

Any idea?

Thanks!!!

Comment: Why not just use a controller on your page?

Comment: You can add the `select` and `option` HTML elements to your page using JavaScript. But when you save the page there will be no automatic binding to properties on the controller. As Adrian suggests, building a list of `SelectOption` in a controller and using `apex:selectList` and `apex:selectOptions` will be simpler.

Comment: Professional Edition :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create select within [JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17001961/javascript-add-select-programmatically)

```
<apex:page >
<script type="text/javascript">
    var __sfdcSessionId = '{!GETSESSIONID()}';
</script>
<script src="../../soap/ajax/36.0/connection.js" type="text/javascript"/>
<script type="text/javascript">     window.onload = setupPage;
function setupPage() {
    var queryResult = sforce.connection.query("Select Id, Name From Account limit 5");
    var array = queryResult.getArray('records');

    var myDiv = document.getElementById("selectOption");
    var selectList = document.createElement("select");
    selectList.id = "mySelect";
    selectList.onchange = myFunction;
    myDiv.appendChild(selectList);

    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        var option = document.createElement("option");
        option.value = array[i].Id;
        option.text = array[i].Name;
        selectList.appendChild(option);
    }
}
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("mySelect").value;
    document.getElementById("choice").innerHTML = "You selected: " + x;
}
</script>

<div id="selectOption"> </div>
<p id="choice"></p> 
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Perfect! Now I just need save with a commandButton action save the value. Thanks!